# RegEx spaces based on previous token

Tags: regex

Looking for a RegEx to capture spaces or dashes based on the previous token.

My current RegEx is:

```
\b\d{2}(\s?\-?)\d{2}(\s?\-?)\d{2}(\s+|\s?)\d{8}\b
```

I only want the spaces or dashes between the `\d{2}` to match if the previous token matched.

As it stands these would incorrectly match:

```
15-1445 10548965
52 1456 12584869
```

I'd only want to match if the previous text matched, for example:

```
15-14-45 10548965
52 14 56 12584869
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a capture group to match whitespace or hyphen and then use it's back-reference to enforce matching same delimiter later:

```bash
\b\d{2}([\s-])\d{2}\1\d{2}\s+\d{8}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5H1HK/1)

Here:

- `([\s-])`: Match whitespace or hyphen and captures it in group #1
- `\1`: Match same character as the captured value in group #1

Comment: That's great, thank you! If I wanted to the first two digits to specifically match "15" or "16" would that be possible? e.g. "15 04 02 10025658"

Comment: Yes that is easy. It would be: `\b1[56]([\s-])\d{2}\1\d{2}\s+\d{8}\b`

Comment: It did indeed, was getting my bracket format wrong. Thanks again.